# Sonar multi module Gradle Android ignore projectBaseDir

Tags: java, android, gradle, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

I have a problem with the configuration of Sonar, I'm trying to configure multi module for the following project:

```
Project:
    app
    lib
        android_core_ui
            nspcoreui
        nspi
```

So I have 3 module to analyse: app, nspcoreui and nspi.
I'm trying the following command

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
./gradlew sonarqube -Dsonar.sourceEncoding="UTF-8" \
-Dsonar.projectVersion="3.10.0-APR-TEST.24-SNAPSHOT" \
-Dsonar.jacoco.reportPaths="app/build/jacoco/testStgDebugUnitTest.exec" \
-Dsonar.host.url="http://localhost:9000" \
-Dsonar.login="API_KEY" \
-Dsonar.projectKey="android_shop" \
-Dsonar.projectName="Android Shop" \
-Dsonar.projectBaseDir="." \
-Dsonar.modules.enabled="true" \
-Dsonar.modules="app,nspi,nspcoreui" \
-Dapp.sonar.projectKey="android_shop_app" \
-Dapp.sonar.projectName="Android Shop App" \
-Dapp.sonar.projectBaseDir="app" \
-Dapp.sonar.sources="src/main" \
-Dapp.sonar.tests="src/main/java,app/src/main/res" \
-Dnspcoreui.sonar.projectBaseDir="lib/android_core_ui/nspcoreui" \
-Dnspcoreui.sonar.projectName="Android Core UI" \
-Dnspcoreui.sonar.projectKey="android_nspcoreui" \
-Dnspcoreui.sonar.tests="src/test/java" \
-Dnspcoreui.sonar.sources="src/main/java,src/main/res" \
-Dnspi.sonar.projectBaseDir="lib/nspi" \
-Dnspi.sonar.projectName="Android NSPI" \
-Dnspi.sonar.projectKey="android_nspi" \
-Dnspi.sonar.tests="src/test/java" \
-Dnspi.sonar.sources="src/main/java,src/main/res";
```

My problem is that all `-Dnspcoreui.sonar.projectBaseDir` and `Dnspi.sonar.projectBaseDir` are totally ignored and the analysis failed with `Project/nspcoreui doesn't exist`

Correct path would be `Project/lib/android_shop_ui/nspcoreui` and `Project/lib/nspi`.

I'm using sonar `classpath 'org.sonarsource.scanner.gradle:sonarqube-gradle-plugin:2.6.1'` and `apply plugin: 'org.sonarqube'` is under the three modules.

Any idea why sonar is ignoring my params ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

as stated in the documentation, you have to apply the sonarqube plugin at the root project and not on every subproject you have.
In the root build.gradle file:

```
apply plugin: "org.sonarqube"
```

And don't apply in on subprojects.

Then the configuration will be much more simple since the modules will be automatically discovered

Comment: Could you please check this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65963755/sonarqube-for-multi-module-project-for-android